# If statement with multiple else if statements in ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that I am converting into SSRS and there is an important function that has multiple ELSE IF statements. Is there a way to get this to work in ssrs?

```
IF ({Command.FOLDERTYPE}= 'PC' and
//1950 - SUB - MAJ FACILITIES SUBDIVISION, 1260 - SUBDIVISION
({Command.SUBCODE} = 1950) or {Command.SUBCODE} = 1260) 
OR (({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'GD' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 900) //900 -    Public Construction
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'WA' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 900)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'SS' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 900)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'SD' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 900)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'ST' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 900)) THEN
'Subdivision'
ELSE IF ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'CO') 
OR (({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'WA' and {@SubtypeCommercial} = true)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'SS' and {@SubtypeCommercial} = true)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'SD' and {@SubtypeCommercial} = true)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'ST' and {@SubtypeCommercial} = true)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'PC' and {@SubtypeCommercial} = true)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'GD' and {@SubtypeCommercial} = true)) THEN
'Commercial'
ELSE IF ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'SF')
OR (({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'WA' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 1210) //1210 -  singe family
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'SS' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 1210)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'SD' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 1210)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'ST' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 1210)
or ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'GD' and {Command.SUBCODE} = 1210)) THEN
'Single Family'
ELSE IF {Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'II' OR ({Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'FR') THEN
'Miscellaneous'
ELSE IF {Command.FOLDERTYPE} = 'GD' THEN
'Grading Permit - No subtype'
```

Comment: look into the SWITCH statement in SSRS.

Comment: I will advice you to make this all conditions adjust in SQL query itself. And get the all formatted and calculated data from database. If that's not in your hand then go with the `CASE` because in this case that will be easy to track than `IIF`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, easiest way is with nested iif in an expression:

```
=iif([first condition], [result if true], iif([second condition], [result if first condition not true, and 2nd is true], [result if neither are true))
```

That's just for two conditions obviously, but you can continue to nest iif statements beyond that in the same manner.